# Divide integer by 16 without using division or cast

Tags: optimization, division, fractions

OKAY... let me rephrase this question...

How can I obtain x 16ths of an integer without using division or casting to double....

Comment: What is the type of frac? If it's an `int`, then if frac is 2, res will be 0 for any value of ref.

Comment: @Jon, I'd go by the text, not the code which is an (incorrect) first pass, I think

Comment: Have you tried "int res = (ref >> 4) * frac"  ?

Comment: it is also an integer... I realize it is not functional like this... however, i would like to avoid casting to floating point types... I just need to figure out how many 16ths there are of any integer... (without using division)

Comment: @Paul: I'm just trying to point out that it's worth getting the simpler-to-understand code working first, before worrying about eliminating division...

Comment: @dwb - that will give 0 for ref between 0 and 15. Probably not what was intended.

Comment: @old-school rules: I suggest you present *working* code first, and then try to adapt it appropriately.

Comment: That is why I added a note at the bottom... I know this code doesn't work; I am trying to convey what I WANT to do without division

Comment: I think what Jon means by working is `int res = (ref * frac)/16`. The adaption is to turn the `/16` into `>> 4`

Comment: Why did you edit out the original expression ? The question is pretty meaningless now...

Comment: @Paul R, I imagine because some answers focused on the (strawman) expression and not on the problem as the OP wanted. It's not meaningless now, IMO.

Comment: @Paul: I think the question would be more meaningful if it had *some* kind of expression that needed to be optimised, rather than just being a vague and rather too general problem statement.

Comment: No, I don't agree. Adding an expression gets the kind of responses it did get ('trust the compiler'). Although it could be more clearly worded, I think the question could be a more general one about how to replace division with other operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int res = (ref * frac) >> 4
```

(but worry a a bit about overflow. How big can ref and frac get? If it could overflow, cast to a longer integer type first)

Answer (score 2):

In any operation of such kind it makes sense to multiply first, then divide. Now, if your operands are integers and you are using a compileable language (eg. C), use shr 4 instead of /16 - this will save some processor cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything here are ints, any optimizing compiler worth its salt will notice 16 is a power of two, and shift frac accordingly -- so long as optimizations are turned on. Worry more about major optimizations the compiler can't do for you.

If anything, you should bracket `ref * frac` and then have the divide, as any value of frac less than 16 will result in 0, whether by shift or divide.

Comment: It's possible the OP isn't using C (etc) as the implementation language but is asking more generally. There were no language-specific tags.

Comment: Language is immaterial, only the number of values a bit can hold. If you want, real "compiler" as "compiler or interpreter" because honestly, a good dynamic language interpreter should notice the same things about primitive number types, IMO.

Comment: Only if it can prove that the values are always numbers, really. If it has to check at runtime, the overhead of checking probably outweighs any possible optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left shift or right shift:

```
public static final long divisionUsingMultiplication(int a, int b) {
    int temp = b;
    int counter = 0;
    while (temp <= a) {
        temp = temp<<1;
        counter++;
    }
    a -= b<<(counter-1);
    long result = (long)Math.pow(2, counter-1);
    if (b <= a) result += divisionUsingMultiplication(a,b);
    return result;
}

public static final long divisionUsingShift(int a, int b) {
    int absA = Math.abs(a);
    int absB = Math.abs(b);
    int x, y, counter;

    long result = 0L;
    while (absA >= absB) {
        x = absA >> 1;
        y = absB;
        counter = 1;
        while (x >= y) {
            y <<= 1;
            counter <<= 1;
        }
        absA -= y;
        result += counter;
    }
    return (a>0&&b>0 || a<0&&b<0)?result:-result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the constraint, but this pseudo code rounds up (?):

```
res = 0
ref= 10
frac = 2
denominator = 16
temp = frac * ref
while temp > 0
   temp -= denominator
   res += 1
repeat
echo res
```

Comment: And probably takes the prize for the slowest implementation. Consider frac = 2, ref = MAXINT/2. It also has the overflow issues of the other solutions

Comment: Hey, I think the whole thing is ill advised! :) Is there a real-world reason for the constraint of no division?

Comment: Division on the platform I work on is about 25 times slower than addition/subtraction/shift and about 10 times slower than multiplication.  For some applications there is enough code doing division in the hot path to try to find alternatives.